# Android communicating between nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am aware that when you would like to communicate between fragments you should do so via the parent activity. It makes sense when the two fragments are on the same level. If one is nested within the second It makes little sense to "go up" only to return "down".

In this scenario the pattern makes sense:

```
   Activity
   ____|____
  /         \
Frag A    Frag B
```

It makes little sense to use the pattern when one is nested within the other:

```
   Activity
      |
    Frag A
      |
    Frag B
```

Is it acceptable to communicate directly using findFragmentByTag(FRAG_X_TAG) if one is nested within the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of this pattern is to use the `Activity` as a `Controller` interface, to which the `Fragment`s are `View`s - they send UI events to the `Controller`, which in turn updates them as appropriate.

This means that the real question here should be "Is Frag A a `Controller` for Frag B" - if so, direct communication would be acceptable. If both are just "dumb Views", they really shouldn't know about each other.

The bottom line is that you want to avoid making spaghetti code, which is possible as long as you enforce separation of concerns.

Comment: If I understand then you are saying that it shouldn't cause any problems but it is bad practice?

Comment: I'm saying that depending on the context, it can be a bad practice - if Frag A holds all the data state needed to display Frag B properly, then it is a de facto controller for Frag B and it wouldn't be a bad practice. If the state for Frag A and Frag B is held in the Activity, it's better to let the Activity control both of them, instead of letting Frag A control Frag B.

Answer (score 0):

According to [API 4.2 documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments), you should use [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29)

You can always use BusEvent library, it eases communication between components, but you may also lose code intelligibility.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use an Event Bus. These are some of the most popular choices:

- Otto by Square: http://square.github.io/otto/
- EventBus by GreenRobot: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I am aware of the option but do not want the dependency just for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Model–view–viewmodel (MVVM) artchitecture that google promotes in Google Architecture components:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}


public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Answer (score -1):

If you want to activte morethan 1 fragment at the same time... then use the method `getChildFragmentManager()`

eg:

I have a main fragment called "ShareSpace" and has 3 child fragment..
//In ShareSpace Fragment

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sharespace, container, false);
    mTabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    mContext=getActivity();
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        ShareSpaceAdapter pagerAdapter = new ShareSpaceAdapter(mContext,getChildFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs_share);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
```

//In Adapter

```
public ShareSpaceAdapter(Context mContext, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    try {
        if (home == null) {
            homeFact = FactoryGenerator.getFactory(Constants.HOME);
            home = homeFact.getHomeManagement(Constants.SHARESPACE);
        }
        local = home.readAssets(mContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    Fragment frgmt = null;

    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:

        frgmt = new ShareSpaceFiles(mContext);
        break;
    case 1:

        frgmt=new ShareSpaceFolder(mContext);
        break;
    case 2:

         frgmt = new ShareSpaceInbox(mContext);
         break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return frgmt;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
        return local.getmFiles();//"FILES";
    case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
        return local.getmFolders();//"FOLDERS";
    case 2:
        return local.getmMessages();//"MESSAGES";

    default:
        return null;

    }

}
```

It will load 3 child fragment at the same time

Comment: I want to communicate between them. not sure you understood my question properly.